# Any idea about clarity only not whole effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

only this kind of high clarity any one give idea of it or something similiar to it

Comment: No in this i only want to know clarity only not the whole effect only clarity it is differnet then that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complex multilayer composition, no one click way to this.

Everything has got a serious color reduction with color selective hue&saturation layers (the lips of a woman are left out with masking and the effect is thinned here and there).

The persons are with extremely careful clipping or masking separated to upper layers and got noise reduction filtering to clean the skin,sharpening and a some artistic filtering to create drawing-likeness. The skin color obviously has got a hue shift from orange to red to achieve something which at least 25 years ago was common in countries like Norway, Sweden, Finland.

The background is probably totally different than the images where the persons were when the photos were shot. It's blurred to increase the apparent foreground sharpness. Note: Blurring isn't global, there are sharp areas to avoid too artificial appearance.

Here's an example (it's made of low res web screenshots, you must have high resolution images for better results)

The original 2 layer composition - a man and a bookshelf, quite a mess, I say:

[image]

Color reduction and skintone hue shift is added. The bookself is still too strong and the man isn't polished:

[image]

The man is smoothened with Redfield Perfectum. It needs still sharpening. Perfectum leaves high contrast borders, but it doesn't sharpen. There are portrait retouching filters which do it, too. As a quick fix sharpening with Unsharp Mask is added:

[image]

The background needs more color reduction and it must be blurred at least near the man. They are done here:

[image]

Finally a cartoonizing filtering is added to the man to lift up strong contrast borders as black lines. The filtering is actually edge detection with layer mode multiply + a hefty contrast boost.

[image]